AWS DMS and generated colums
i'm having problems with generated columns in my migration (DMS) process from on premise (MySQL) to aws (Aurora).
Different blog posts for example: https://medium.com/ekino-france/8-things-to-know-when-using-aws-dms-for-db-relocation-5904a117fb99 recommend that you should exclude generated columns via transformation rules. But I don't see any option there to exclude column during DMS process. There are options to remove and mess with prefixes/suffixes but don't see an option to just keep column empty/unchanged.
Can someone give me an example of transformation rule which exclude one column in AWS DMS ?
I have read the https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TableMapping.SelectionTransformation.Transformations.html bud did not notice the option from there. Nor did i find proper option combination under "Database migration tasks" (AWS console GUI).
